# Difference between 2 arrays using perl array_diff utility

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, diff, array-difference

I am trying to run array_diff on 2 arrays.

```
sub array_diff(\@\@) {
    my %e = map { $_ => undef } @{$_[1]};
    return @{[
        ( grep { (exists $e{$_}) ? ( delete $e{$_} ) : ( 1 ) } @{ $_[0] } ),
        keys %e
    ] };
}

my $col = 'col';
my $stg = 'stg';
my @blocks = qw( block1 block2 block3 block4 block5 );
my %hash; @{$hash{$col}{$stg}} = qw( block1 block2 block3 );

my @diff = array_diff(@all_blocks, @{$hash{$col}{$stg}});
print ("diff : @diff\n");
```

It gives me the following error when above line is executed:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @diff in string at get_blocks.pl line 56.
Type of arg 2 to main::array_diff must be array (not reference constructor) at get_blocks.pl line 55, near "})"
syntax error at get_blocks.pl line 55, near "})"
Execution of get_blocks.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

However when I try the same without an array of hash it works

```
my @a = qw( a b c d e);
my @b = qw( c d  );

sub array_diff(\@\@) {
    my %e = map { $_ => undef } @{$_[1]};
    return @{[
        ( grep { (exists $e{$_}) ? ( delete $e{$_} ) : ( 1 ) } @{ $_[0] } ),
        keys %e
    ] };
}
# symmetric difference
my @diff = array_diff(@a, @b);
print ("diff : @diff\n");
```

Result:

```
diff : a b e
```

Comment: I absolutely back Schwern's words to loose the prototypes and `@{[...]}`. (And also note how to work through errors.) And then, there are very good libraries which deal with relationships between arrays. (Now, I think it's great to roll your own -- but then compare it to a good library for interface, error checking, performance, features...)

Comment: Tip: `return @{[ ... ]}` is a weird way of doing `return ...;` (Well, they may behave different in scalar context, but not in this case because `grep` returns the number of matching elements in scalar context.)

Comment: The code you have posted does not exhibit the behaviour you claim it does. Please fix your question

Answer (score 4):

We can consult [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) to figure out the errors and warnings.

> `Possible unintended interpolation of @diff in string at get_blocks.pl line 56.`
>
> (W ambiguous) You said something like '@foo' in a double-quoted string but there was no array @foo in scope at the time. If you wanted a literal @foo, then write it as `\@foo`; otherwise find out what happened to the array you apparently lost track of.

You're doing `"@diff"` but `@diff` is not declared.

> `Type of arg 2 to main::array_diff must be array (not reference constructor) at get_blocks.pl line 55, near "})"`
>
> (F) This function requires the argument in that position to be of a certain type. Arrays must be @NAME or @{EXPR} . Hashes must be %NAME or %{EXPR} . No implicit dereferencing is allowed--use the {EXPR} forms as an explicit dereference. See perlref.

Just as it says, the `\@` prototype must take an array, not a reference.

```
# Bad
array_diff([1,2,3], [4,5,6]);

# Good
array_diff(@{[1,2,3]}, @{[4,5,6]});
```

Your sample code and your errors do not match. `@diff` is declared and you have de-referenced `$hash{$col}{$stg}`.

---

I would recommend against using prototypes. They're not like declaring a function's arguments in other languages. Instead, they're for emulating the magic behavior of built-in functions.

Instead, pass in the references.

```
my @diff = array_diff(\@all_blocks, $hash{$col}{$stg});
```

[True subroutine signatures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures) are unfortunately still experimental.

---

There's no need for [the baby-cart operator `@{[]}`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby-cart) around `grep`. `grep` already returns a new array, there's no need to clone it. It complicates the code and wastes memory.